# How to play local mp3 file with audioplayer plugin in Flutter

Tags: flutter, audio-player

How to play local mp3 file with [audioplayer 0.2.0](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/audioplayer) in Flutter.

pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
    assets:
    - sounds/music.mp3
```

main.dart

```
Future<ByteData> loadAsset() async {
    return await rootBundle.load('sounds/music.mp3');
}

// FIXME: This code is not working.
Future playLocal() async {
    final result = await audioPlayer.play(loadAsset());
    if (result == 1) setState(() => playerState = PlayerState.playing);
}
```

Can I get local assets path from rootBundle?
Can I pay audio from ByteData on audioPlayer?

Comment: The package "audioplayers" instead of "audioplayer" has a nice class AudioCache meant exactly for this purpose.
More info here: https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/blob/master/doc/audio_cache.md

Comment: You can now read about  the AudioCache class here: https://github.com/AgeOfLearning/flutter_audioplayers/blob/master/doc/audio_cache.md

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `audioplayer` plugin currently only supports network paths and files. You can move an asset to a temporary folder and play it with this code:

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

...

```
final file = new File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/music.mp3');
await file.writeAsBytes((await loadAsset()).buffer.asUint8List());
final result = await audioPlayer.play(file.path, isLocal: true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
I was able to play mp3 it this way.

Comment: How to set assets/sounds/1.mp3 to play?

Answer (score 4):

I have just created a repo in github that uses audioplayers plugin to stream local mp3 files. This player can seek, pause, stop and play local audio

https://github.com/samupra/local_flutter_audio_player

Comment: Thanks for the sample

Answer (score 3):

A way that worked for me was to create the assets file and load the mp3 file in to the directory.

Then load the file using the Future

```
 AudioPlayer audio = await AudioCache.play("filetobeloaded.mp3");
```

Comment: how to pause or stop this audio? using this method

Answer (score 0):

use this code it'll work
don't mention folder name if already mentioned in pubsec.yaml

```
onPressed: () async{
          final player = AudioPlayer();
          await player.play(AssetSource("note1.wav"));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).