# Play custom audio

Tags: audio, flutter

I'm trying to play an mp3 I will bundle with my app. I added it in the assets, just like the images, added to the pubspec, but can't make it play.

I tried two libraries, rxlabz/audioplayer and evrone/flutter_audio (medrecorder_audio), to no avail.

The first I tryed configuring to isLocal: true, added every conceivable callback, but it just returned the error:

> Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer

Which I couldn't relate to flutter/dart but found is a common error on Android, related to not calling prepare method. I checked their code, though, and they seem to be calling. I thought it my be async, so I waited a while after creating the player to call start, no luck.

The latter just gives the error "startPlay: FAIL" when I start play.

It seems these libs are made to play an audio that's on the user's cellphone, but I'm not sure. I want to play my own custom mp3 that I will bundle as an asset. Would someone shed some light?

Comment: have you checked this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46486475/how-to-play-local-mp3-file-with-audioplayer-plugin-in-flutter/46498239#46498239

Comment: @aziza that seems to be the perfect solution, but gives the same kind of error on mediplayer prepare. Do I have to enable some sort of permission to use audio? I tried playing a System Sound and it worked

Comment: @aziza I made it! Finally! The problem was, my file was a wav, it needed to be mp3. Thanks so much!

Comment: glad you have found your way to it, please consider answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @aziza's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46486475/how-to-play-local-mp3-file-with-audioplayer-plugin-in-flutter/46498239#46498239), and a lot of experimenting, I found the problem.

The file to be played need to me an MP3; WAV just won't work, and will give a very cryptic error.

[This class](https://github.com/luanpotter/flame/blob/master/lib/audio.dart) shows in details how to do it.