# Flutter - How do I play ambient sounds?

Tags: audio, flutter

I am developing a flutter app. I want to let the user select some sounds.
When selected, I want the app to play its mp3 file in the assets folder. I tried with AudioPlayer plugin but I haven't achieved to play local files... 
I have been searching for awhile and I haven't found any good answer to my questions, furthermore, the posts were created 2 or 1 year ago, so maybe we need an updated answer.

I have found this post: [How to play local mp3 file with audioplayer plugin in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46486475/how-to-play-local-mp3-file-with-audioplayer-plugin-in-flutter)
but my project doesn't find this package `import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';`  [**THIS PART IS SOLVED**]

And when flutter will have a built-in audio manager? Are they/you working on it?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Also, I would like to play different mp3 at the same time, with different volume. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `import` directive you see tells Dart that a particular source file uses classes from a different source file. The `package:` prefix tells Dart that the imported file is part of an external dependency. So you need to tell your project that you have a dependency. This is done in the `pubspec.yaml` [file](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec).

Dart's pub dependency manager takes care of finding the right version of the dependency for you, and downloading it. Add the [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) package to your `pubspec.yaml` file. Each package's *installing* tab shows how to do this.

You can find a whole library of useful flutter (and Dart) packages [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages).

`path_provider` is a special type of package called a `plugin` which contains some Dart code together with iOS and Android specific code. This is necessary because playing audio or creating local files is platform specific.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful info, I needed it! But still I have problems making it work the way I would like, I edited my post explaining my problem!

Comment: You would probably need to write your own plugin, but you could base anything you write on the existing AudioPlayer plugin. One of the benefits of Dart/Flutter is that it is open source.

Comment: Yea, I have been lucky this time and I've found this  [fork of audioPlayer](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayer) with my special needs, thank you!